# Problem in a list with previously created variables. Error local variable 'Victory' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, boolean

I have Victory, Draw, Lose variables for a hockey game. Obviously, based on the final result of a game, only one of these variables will be True. For this reason I created them inside a try and except: pass.

Now I would like to print only one of these variables (the True one, for example Victory, because Victory becomes True based on a scraping of the results of the hockey match), but I get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Victory' referenced before assignment` when I search to print the True variable, because Victory was already named before the assignment. Given the simplicity of the problem, I report only the part useful for the resolution:

Maybe I shouldn't use a list

```
#scraping and assignment of Point_Team_A and Point_Team_B
...

try:
    Victory = Point_Team_A > Point_Team_B 
    Draw = Point_Team_A == Point_Team_B
    Lose = Point_Team_A < Point_Team_B
except:
    pass

result=[Victory, Draw, Lose] #great problem is here

print (*filter(None, result), sep='\n') #and here
```

For example if the result is a Victory, I want to get the **output**: `Victory`

NOTE:  I use try / except because only one (1) variable will be True between Victory, Draw, Lose. The two False variables will be recognized as an error, because I previously created Point_Team_A and Point_Team_B inside an if / else condition. Subsequently I use Point_Team_A and B to create the 3 variables above. For example, if the result of a hockey match is 7-3, it means that team A has won, because Victory = Point_Team_A> Point_Team_B. Consequently Draw and Lose will be recognized by Python as an error, for this use try / except.

Comment: If an exception occurs then your variables are not set, therefore it will post that error.

Comment: If the `try/except` block fails, `Victory` (and `Draw` and `Lose`) will not be defined. Try adding `Victory = Draw = Lose = False` before that block

Comment: I suggest you to use a regular `if - else` statement for this. something like `if Point_Team_A > Point_Team_B: print "Victory"`. On python is better simple over complex.

Comment: @Germán Ruelas I tried as you said with the if and print condition, but I get the error again: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Victory' referenced before assignment. Does this mean there is a problem in the try / except block?

Comment: @LancelotduLac we don't actually know whether or not this code will produce an error since we don't know what `Point_Team_A` and `Point_Team_B` are. It is possible for  `Point_Team_A > Point_Team_B` to produce a TypeError (i.e. one is an int and another is a string), which would lead to the variables not being defined.

Comment: @Mark Good point. A TypeError would effectively be hidden by the except/pass construct

Comment: I think the main point should be that you only put something in a `try/except` block if you think there could be an error. In this case if there *is* an error (*any* error, which is also an anti-pattern — you should catch specific errors), `pass` is a totally inappropriate way to handle it because you have left the code in an unknown state. If you *know* there can't be an error, then `try/catch` is superfluous.

Comment: @Mark I use try / except because only one (1) variable will be True between Win, Draw, Lose. The two False variables will be recognized as an error, because I previously created Point_Team_A and Point_Team_B inside an if / else condition. Subsequently I use Point_Team_A and B to create the 3 variables above. For example, if the result of a hockey match is 7-3, it means that team A has won, because Victory = Point_Team_A> Point_Team_B. Consequently Draw and Lose will be recognized by Python as an error, for this use try / except. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Jas_99 If the variables Point_Team_A and Point_Team_B are comparable, Victory, Draw and Lose will all exist with appropriate values. One of them will be True, the others False. There is no reason for you to perform the comparisons and assignments in a try/except **unless** there's a possibility that the objects are not comparable in which case you should not ignore the exception

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
if a_points > b_points:
    print('victory')
elif a_points == b_points:
    print('draw')
else:
    print('defeat')
```

your code as is, when it works, would literally only ever print `True`

if you want another way to reproduce this error you're seeing, try this:

```
def f():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass

    print(x)
```

what's happening is that the python interpreter knows that the name `x` exists in scope but also that it's never *bound* to anything (because the exception occurs before the assignment). so you get `UnboundLocalError`

Comment: For technical reasons, I would not like to use if a_points> b_points directly, I would like to use Victory, Draw and Lose. I tried to do as one user suggested in the comments (I think it's the same solution as yours) with if Victory: print ("victory"), but I still get the error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Victory' referenced before assignment. I believe it is the same with your solution as well. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: as this is a technical website, maybe you could provide those reasons? and because my code doesn't use the variable `Victory`, there's no way that error would ever occur.

Comment: Because to simplify the question I only wrote Victory, Draw, Lose. I actually have about 100 combinations of results (for example 2 consecutive Victory, or a Draw after a Lose, etc). For the sake of order and simplicity, I would like to assign a_points> b_points (and similar) directly to the variable name

Comment: yeah, you don't want local variable names for this. you probably want a list of descriptions and then add each individual description to that list. so like, "if they won, `descriptions.append('victory')`. if they've won twice in a row, `descriptions.append('two wins')`. but with 100+ combinations (implying, what, you're looking at the last 5 games - 3 outcomes ** 5 games?), it doesn't really seem manageable.

Comment: I have already created the 100 combinations correctly. It is not a management problem. Yours is a good solution, but it is not the correct solution because my code is a little more difficult than you are imagining

Comment: I use try / except because only one (1) variable will be True between Win, Draw, Lose. The two False variables will be recognized as an error, because I previously created Point_Team_A and Point_Team_B inside an if / else condition. Subsequently I use Point_Team_A and B to create the 3 variables above. For example, if the result of a hockey match is 7-3, it means that team A has won, because Victory = Point_Team_A> Point_Team_B. Consequently Draw and Lose will be recognized by Python as an error, for this use try / except.

Answer (score 0):

Python variables fall into one of two categories: **global** and **local**. A variable is global if it is defined at **file scope**. Contrary, a local variable is one that is defined within a **python block**. By a python block, I mean any of the python constructs that introduces a new code block delimited by indentation(notably a function definition)

Unlike other languages(C++ for instance), local python variables can be accessed from an outside scope. This is what typically raises an **UnboundLocalError** exception. Consider the following code:

```
def check_age(age):
    if age < 18:
        info = 'too young'
    elif age > 18:
        info = 'too old'
    
    return info
```

`check_age()` works just fine until it is invoked with the value **18**. Because none of the conditional statements within `check_age()` defines the value of `info` when `age` is 18,`info` wont have a value(unbound) when the function is invoked with the value 18.
Consequently, accessing `info` later through the return statement raises an **UnboundLocalError**

In your specific situation, `try` defines a new block(or scope) where you carry out some assignments to a couple of variables. You later access those variables in an enclosing scope.
**The only immediately obvious cause of an `UnboundLocalError` is that an exception is raised within your `try` block(particularly on the first line) which is silenced by `pass` in your `except` block, causing `Victory` not to be assigned a value. Hence trying to access `Victory` through `list = [Victory, Draw, Lose]` raises the said exception**. This could only mean that there is a problem with the values being passed to the `>` operator on the first line within your `try` block. Probably the operator is not defined for at least one of the values.

The bottomline is to check your scraped data to ensure that you are passing the right values.

Answer (score -2):

When there is an exception in the try block the variables created in the try block will not be available in an outside try block, so create a variable and initialize it either in the outside try block or inside except

```
Victory = Draw = Lose = False
try:
    Victory = Point_Team_A > Point_Team_B 
    Draw = Point_Team_A == Point_Team_B
    Lose = Point_Team_A < Point_Team_B
except:
    pass

result=[Victory, Draw, Lose] 

print (*filter(None, result), sep='\n')
```

Comment: @LancelotduLac that's assuming that `Point_Team_A` and `Point_Team_B` are comparable. if they're not (e.g. they're both `None`), that will raise a type error, which will be caught and, depending on where this code is run (i.e. in a function or globally), either a `NameError` or an `UnboundLocalError` will result.

Comment: @Sreekanth T I tried your code, but it didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: @Jas_99 could you please tell us what exactly the values of `Point_Team_A` and `Point_Team_B`

Comment: @Jas_99 check once https://www.online-python.com/oOwc7GpA8N